# FactoryBot create_list duplicate records - uniqueness validation falls through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a association between a plan and a price history, with the constraint that the time stamp in the price history has to be unique for each plan:

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :price_histories
end
```

```
class PriceHistory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :plan
  validates :time_utc_milli, presence: true
  validates :time_utc_milli, uniqueness: { scope: :plan_id, message: "Only 1 time per plan" }
end
```

A plan always needs to have one price history, where `current: true`.

Now I created the following factories, but the problem is, that every now and then, I get a validation error that a price history with the timestamp already exists. They seem to come up randomly and I do't know what I am doing wrong.

```
factory :plan do
    name { Faker::Name.unique.name }
    ...

    factory :plan_with_price_histories do
      transient do
         price_histories_count { 15 }
      end

      after(:create) do |plan, evaluator|
        time = Time.now.utc + 6.hours
        create :price_history, plan: plan, current: true, time_utc_milli: time.beginning_of_minute - time.min % 5 * 60
        create_list(:price_history, evaluator.price_histories_count, plan: plan)
      end
    end
  end

  factory :price_history do
    sequence(:time_utc_milli) { |n| Time.now.utc.beginning_of_day + (n * 5.minutes) }

    trait :current_price_history do
      time_utc_milli { Time.now.utc.beginning_of_minute - Time.now.utc.min % 5 * 60 }
      current { true }
    end
  end
```

It seems to be like `create_list` is creating records simultaneously, but I tried to replace it with a simple loop and created one record with a time and it still happened.